# How many collection document pairs can be used in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app that has this schema:

```
HOME -> Collection -> Document -> Collection -> Document
```

And code:

```
db.collection('coll').doc('doc').collection('subcoll').doc('subdoc')
```

But the problem I'm facing is that my app requires more pairs (1 to 3) of collections and documents nested in depth. Is this a problem?

How many pairs of collections and documents can I have in chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain in depth up to a maximum of **100** subcollections. As per the offial documentation regarding [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).

> Maximum depth of subcollections: 100

Regarding your question:

> Is this a problem?

As far as I know, Firestore can as quickly look up a node at level 1 as it can at level 100.
So for a database as yours, depth should not be a factor that affects speed on a technical level.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum depth of subcollections is 100, as detailed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields) in the Firestore documentation.