# Right structure for Firebase for low cost and best readability

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am migrating from Supabase to Firebase.

[image]

here is my current setup (example). In reality, it is a little big bigger with more attributes.

Now I am migrating the product data to Firebase Firestore. The main question is. Should I store sizes, and images in a subcollection from the product, so I need to read all subcollection when I fetch a product? Or should I just store sizes and images in the product itself?
When I store it in the product there is a lot of data. And it is not so easy to see the data easily on the web of Firebase. But I only need to fetch once for all Data. The subcollection is for better readability and is easier to change.

In the same, I would ask for accounts. How to manage everything there. All referenced tables as subcollections or in the main document.

Answer (score 0):

> So I need to read all subcollections when I fetch a product. Or should I just store sizes and images in the product itself?

In my honest opinion, you should store all product data inside a single document. In this way, you'll save additional reads.

> When I store it in the product there is a lot of data.

There will be no problem, as long as you stay below the [maximum 1 Mib limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields).

> The same I would ask for accounts. How to manage everything there.

The same as above.

However, please also note that [there is no "perfect", "the best" or "the correct" solution for structuring a Cloud Firestore database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53057707/5246885).

Comment: Do you have any tips for managing large data in Firestore ?

Comment: What do you mean by "managing"?

Comment: When I make all subcollections to the main document. There is a lot of Data in the document, when you access it on the web firebase console

Comment: The sub-collections don't count toward the parent document quota. So there will no problem with that.

Comment: Would it be a good decision to use collection or is this not agood idea ?

Comment: It's a good idea if that is your requirement. Perhaps this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54266846/5246885) will help.